# Syntax error on powershell but code works in reg add

Tags: powershell, syntax, syntax-error

Basically I have a code that works when it is separate but when I combine them I get a syntax error. I know both parts work individually but not together. The two parts below are

```
Start-process Powershell -verb runas
```

and

```
$Computername = Read-Host "Please put in Computer Name or IP Address" -AsString
reg add "\\$Computername\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Printers\PointAndPrint" /v RestrictDriverInstallationToAdministrators /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f 
Pause
```

when I combine them I get the error

> Please put in Computer Name or IP Address -AsString: 1.1.1.1
> ERROR: Invalid syntax.
> Type "REG ADD /?" for usage.

I know the `Start-process Powershell -verb runas` is correct as it opens PowerShell in admin mode and asks me for my input.

And I know the rest of the code works because if I just use the code below it works as intended

```
$Computername = Read-Host "Please put in Computer Name or IP Address" -AsString
reg add "\\$Computername\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Printers\PointAndPrint" /v RestrictDriverInstallationToAdministrators /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f 
Pause
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong, the full code is below.

```
Start-process Powershell -verb runas {$Computername = Read-Host "Please put in Computer Name or IP Address" -AsString
reg add "\\$Computername\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Printers\PointAndPrint" /v RestrictDriverInstallationToAdministrators /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f 
Pause}
```

I have tried taking off the `-AsString`. I still had the same error. I have changed quite a bit of syntax but can not shake the error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
Could you please [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) properly?   Thanks in advance.  

Answer (score 2):

- [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) does *not* have an `-AsString` switch.

  - It does have an `-AsSecureString` switch, asking that a [`System.Security.SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Security.SecureString) instance be returned, but that's not what you're looking for.
  - In the absence of this switch, a string is *invariably* returned.
  - Any argument that `Read-Host` doesn't recognize as a *named* argument referring to one of its declared parameters implicitly becomes a part of the `-Prompt` parameter value, i.e. part of the *prompt string*, so `-AsString` simply becomes an (unwanted) part of the prompt string presented to the user. Therefore, simply *omit* it.
- [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) launches an *external program* (child process).

  - Its *positional* parameters are `-FilePath` and `-ArgumentList` so that's what `Powershell` and `{$Computername = Read-Host ... }` bind to, respectively.
  - The `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`) parameter accepts an array of *strings* (`[string[]]`), given that it is only *string* arguments that can be passed to external programs.

    - Using a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) `{ ... }` means is *not* supported per se: If you use one, its *verbatim contents* (excluding `{` and `}`) are passed as a *single string*.
- The Windows PowerShell CLI ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)) defaults to interpreting any positional arguments that aren't known CLI parameters as being passed to the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter, i.e. as forming PowerShell source code to be executed.

  - `"` characters on the *command line* that *aren't escaped* are assumed to have purely syntactic function *on the command line*, and are therefore *stripped* during PowerShell's command-line parsing.
  - Any `"` characters to be *passed through* to `-Command`, i.e. those that should form *part of the PowerShell source code to execute* must be escaped *as* `\"`.

---

Therefore:

```bash
# Note how the embedded " chars. are escaped as \"
Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell '
  $Computername = Read-Host \"Please specify a Computer Name or IP Address\"
  reg add \"\\$Computername\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Printers\PointAndPrint\" /v RestrictDriverInstallationToAdministrators /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f 
  pause
'
```